# returning security credentails of an IAmUser using Java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I am trying to access the **Summary** from Sign-in credentials of an IAmUser using Java v2 API. Is there any way I could get that? I am unable to find anything in the documentation provided. Here is a screenshot explaining what I need to get.

[image]

Comment: Do you want to get if an user has console management access?

Comment: @OmarRosadio I want to get IAmUser EC2 acceess

Comment: If you refer to the access key and secret access key then it is not possible

Comment: @OmarRosadio I am just trying to know whether an EC2 instance has interactive login users or not

Comment: AWS IAM Users and EC2 users (OS users) are different things. They are not related. A person can have an IAM User but not OS user to access to EC2. If you want to list the users from an instance then you need to run a command on the instance to get that

Comment: @OmarRosadio could you please guide me to some documents where it mentions the details regarding this? I am unable to get anything from the documentation

Comment: Can users SSH to EC2 instances using their AWS user name and password?
No. User security credentials created with IAM are not supported for direct authentication to customer EC2 instances. Managing EC2 SSH credentials is the customer’s responsibility within the EC2 console.

https://aws.amazon.com/iam/faqs/

Comment: About list the OS users, you can run the command "cat /etc/passwd" for linux distributions

Comment: @OmarRosadio my concern is to check whether there is any interactive login user available for an EC2 instance? the way you mentioned is for linux only. If the EC2 instance is of Windows machine, this command will no longer work.

Comment: I don't understand why do you refer with "interactive login user for an EC2 instance"

Comment: @OmarRosadio I am working on an application where I need to know whether my EC2 instance has interactive login or not. Application needs to check it automatically using some API call to AWS. There are a few functions to perform after it finds that the interactive login is there for a given EC2 instance. That is why I am looking for to find interactive login for an EC2 instance

Comment: @OmarRosadio I have posted a question here. https://stackoverflow.com/q/70703700/7497127
This question I think does not match what I am trying to ask. Please have a look at it. I will delete this question later. Thanks a lot