# Checking whether an EC2 instance have any interactive login user

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am working on an application where I need to know whether a given EC2 instance has interactive login users. By interactive login user, I mean a user that can log in on the console with the UID and password(or other credentials such as ssh cert). After that, I have to perform a few steps as per my requirements.
I am trying to find an API that cold return whether an EC2 instance has an interactive login user or not but could not find one from the documentation. Is there any such API that exists?

**Update**
This might clear what I am trying to ask.
**Does any of the EC2 have user accounts that can log in on the EC2's console ?**

Comment: "I am working on an application where I need to know whether a given EC2 instance has interactive whether interactive login users exist or not" this seems weird to me, possibly an XY problem.  I don't know of any simple way to introspect whether an EC2 instance has an accessible user.

Comment: @DanielFarrell sorry if that sounds weired. But that is still a requirement in a huge size application that I can not avoid at the moment. Could you please guide me to some documentation where some hints are provided regarding this?

Comment: @DanielFarrell I have updated the question. I might have explained the question ambiguously earlier.

Comment: The ability to login to the Amazon EC2 management console is completely independent to the ability to login to an EC2 instance. Logins to the instance are managed by the Operating System that is installed on the instance -- AWS has no control over the ability to login to an instance. (Well, upon first boot it does install a keypair, but after that it has no influence.) So, are you wanting to manage logins to the EC2 management console, or logins to the EC2 instance itself?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein could you please read the **Update** section in my question. Does that clarifies the problem?

Comment: no, still not clear what/why you want to achieve. EC2 instance is just a virtual machine. So  - can you answer your question on a linux (assumption) VM?  (hmm..  ec2 allows ssm sessions, but you could disable that)

Comment: You ask: "Does any of the EC2 have user accounts that can log in on the EC2's console?" There is no such entity as an "EC2 user account". There are IAM Users who can login to the AWS management console and, depending on their permissions, can create, view and delete AWS resources (such as EC2 instances). However, IAM Users cannot login to an EC2 instance since the ability to login to an instance is managed by the Operating System installed on the instance. This is where keypairs are used (Linux) or Username and Password (Windows).

Comment: As @JohnRotenstein already explained, your question is very vague/incomprehensible and that you have the keypair installed for a user(different for different OS) which you can find here.https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/managing-users.html